# What is eating my strawberries? NSW Australia (clean cut)

Tags: fruits, strawberries, soft-fruit

I can't find what could be eating my strawberries. As soon as they are ready, I am always 8 hours of sleep to late to collect them. I put a net that is almost impossible or a bird (although they may get crafty?)
I have mostly Indian mynah around. I have not seen any lizard nearby and that's about it on what I can see.[image]
Attaching photo.

Usually is like a very clean cut, not messy as other pictures I found.

It is usually more taken than the one on this picture but it seems more "cut" than messed around or with deep holes in it.

Comment: What's around for gastropods? Slugs and snails can leave quite a neat "cut" and love strawberries, while laughing at the average fence.

Comment: Does look like slug/snail damage.

Comment: Should I use those small pellets that kills them around it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned it's definitely damage from snails, we get similar damage if we have neglected to spread the slug bait.

> Snails eat a wide variety of foods. They will munch on anything from lettuce and other leafy greens to ripe fruits like strawberries and blueberries. There are a few snails that prefer eating fruit more than others, which is why they have been given a common name: strawberry pig.

From [snailpedia](https://www.snailpedia.com/can-snails-eat-strawberries/)

Apart from slug bait, some suggested remedies quoted are **Coffee**, **Vinegar**, **Garlic** and **Eggshells** and **Citrus Peels**.

> There are several ways to keep these pests from your favorite fruit; however, the safest and pocket-friendly way to keep them off is doing it the organic/traditional ways. Here are 5 tips on keeping your strawberries slug and snails free!

From [thehometome](https://thehometome.com/keep-slugs-and-snails-away-from-strawberry-plants/).

I don't think that eggshells will work, the snail's foot is pretty robust, but other remedies might work.

Comment: Coffee, Vinegar, Garlic and Eggshells and Citrus Peels would work how?

Comment: I have quoted it and provided a reference to it.  It is not my claim.  And I am debunking the eggshell right away.